# Workbench target simulator

Tags: runtime-error, workbench, vxworks

I m trying to launch a small test project using workbench on the target simulator. The project s being build successfuly but it fails to run.
The error message that i had was" failed to  execute launch step" , and the possible cause would " failed to launch target server for connection 'vxsim'(registery localhost) ". 
Anyone could hepl i will be grateful. 
Thanks.